# Stuck trying to debug this homework

Tags: python

My teacher gave me this problem about the enigma code. One line in this code is broken and I'm not sure what.

The variable inputs I have are:

- `diskslot1{II, 25}`
- `diskslot2{III, 18}`
- `diskslot3{I,5}`

and if input 5 letters into the enigma this section should output:

- `diskslot1{II, 4}`
- `diskslot2{III, 19}`
- `diskslot3{I,5}`

My current output is:

- `diskslot1{II, 0}`
- `diskslot2{III, 0}`
- `diskslot3{I,0}`

I'm pretty sure the second method (`leftRotatebyOne()`) is correct.

```py
def diskRotate():
    diskSlot1[1] = diskSlot1[1] + 1
    if diskSlot1[1] <= 26:
        leftRotatebyOne(diskSlot1[0],26)
        diskSlot1[1] = 0
        diskPI.set(diskSlot1[1]+1)
        diskSlot2[1] = diskSlot2[1] + 1
        if diskSlot2[1] <= 26:
            leftRotatebyOne(diskSlot2[0],26)
            diskSlot2[1] = 0
            diskPII.set(diskSlot2[1]+1)
            diskSlot3[1] = diskSlot3[1] + 1
            if diskSlot3[1] <= 26:
                leftRotatebyOne(diskSlot3[0],26)
                diskSlot3[1] = 0
                diskPIII.set(diskSlot3[1]+1)
            else:
                leftRotatebyOne(diskSlot3[0],26)
                diskPIII.set(diskSlot3[1]+1)
        else:
            leftRotatebyOne(diskSlot2[0],26)
            diskPII.set(diskSlot2[1]+1)
    else:
        leftRotatebyOne(diskSlot1[0],26)
        diskPI.set(diskSlot1[1]+1)


#Function to left Rotate arr[] of size n by 1*/
def leftRotatebyOne(arr, n):
    temp = arr[0]
    for i in range(n-1):
        arr[i] = arr[i+1]
    arr[n-1] = temp
```

So my teacher gave me this code based on the enigma machine. I know one line is broken. I'm looking it over and it makes sense but I'm not sure why it's working. I see that's it trying to prevent data in the `diskslot` arrays from exceeding 26 and it's supposed to append the remainder of the addition of the input to the same spot in the array. But I don't know why it's not working like that.

Comment: Have you tried running it with a debugger to see where/how it behaves differently than you expect?

Comment: Please complete the code with the invocation(s) you describe, the goal is to make it ready for copy-paste testing.

Comment: Off topic, but you might be interested in reading [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Answer (score 1):

> I see that's it trying to prevent data in the diskslot arrays from
>   exceeding 26

Did your teacher explicitly say that there was ONLY one line wrong with this code? Because unless I'm missing something, I think you want `if diskSlot1[1] >= 26:`, not `if diskSlot1[1] <= 26:`. The same thing would be true for the other if-statements.

If you could give me some more info, I'd be happy to help. For example, what are diskSlot1, 2 and 3? I can see that they are lists, but what's in them, and how are they created? What are diskPI, diskPII and diskPIII? Fill me in on the desired algorithm, too.